# PIL putpalette error

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

when I use PIL, I got a error. Read a img and convert to 'P' mode. Then I use `img.putpalette(palette)`,`len(palette)` equals 768.And the range of pattle was 0~255.

```
png = Image.fromarray(labelMap).convert('P')
png.putpalette(cmap)
png.save(pngPath, format='PNG')
```

And I got a raise **ValueError: invalid palette size**, So I want know why and how to solve this problem.

edit..

I found a problem, when length of palette smaller than 192, this code works well, and... I don't know why.

Thanks much.

Comment: That's odd. As [the PIL docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putpalette) say, "the palette sequence must contain 768 integer values, where each group of three values represent the red, green, and blue values for the corresponding pixel index". The palette-mapped modes of the PNG format _do_ support a variety of palette sizes, but when working on such images with PIL, I get an error if the palette size isn't 768.

Comment: How are you creating `cmap`?

Comment: I fix this problem with `np.uint8(cmap).tolist()`,Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Before you use 'cmap',you need to transform it to a list.So you can use 'list(cmap)' instead of 'cmap'.

Answer (score 0):

This also occurred to me when I used a palette with dtype that is not `np.uint8`. Converting to `np.uint8` worked for me.